# Can the second 'I' be omitted in 'I am ... and I am ...'

Tags: conjunction-reduction

For example, if I want to say

> **I am** grateful to have been offered a place on the program **and I am** very happy to accept the offer.

Is it better or not to omit the second 'I'?

> **I am** grateful to have been offered a place on the program **and am** very happy to accept the offer.

Omitting the second 'I' looks a bit strange for me..

Comment: you could also omit "am"

Comment: Definitely a duplicate, and @Archie's right, either leave out both (I am) or neither. *I am **grateful** ... **and very happy to accept***.